# SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password) in Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am new to Ansible and I am trying to implement it. I tried all the possible ways present on the Internet and also all questions related to it, but still I can't resolve the error. How can I fix it?

I installed Ansible playbook on my MacBook Pro. I created a VM whose IP address is 10.4.1.141 and host IP address is 10.4.1.140.

I tried to connect to my VM using the host via SSH. It connected by the following command:

```
ssh user@10.4.1.141
```

And I got the shell access. This means my SSH connection is working fine.

Now I tried the following command for Ansible:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

And the content in the `/etc/ansible/host` is `10.4.1.141`.

Then it shows the following error:

> 10.4.1.141 | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).

> while connecting to 10.4.1.141:22

It is sometimes useful to rerun the command using `-vvvv`, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

Then I tried creating the `config` file in `.ssh/` folder on the host machine, but the error is still the same.

The content of the `config` file is:

```
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

which is the path to my private key.

Then I ran the same command `ansible all -m ping` and got the same error again.

When I tried another command,

```
ansible all -m ping -u user --ask-pass
```

Then it asked for the SSH password. I gave it (I am very sure the password is correct), but I got this error:

> 10.4.1.141 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.

This is the log using `-vvvv`:

```
<10.4.1.141> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: rajatg
<10.4.1.141> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<10.4.1.141> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/rajatg/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.4.1.141 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445512455.7-116096114788007 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445512455.7-116096114788007 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445512455.7-116096114788007'
10.4.1.141 | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    while connecting to 10.4.1.141:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

I am still not able to figure it out what the problem is. It is my last choice to ask it here after doing my all research. [This is the link I referred to](https://valdhaus.co/writings/ansible-mac-osx/).

Comment: show us how does your `/etc/ansible/hosts` file looks like .

Comment: I mentioned it in the description. There is only a single line `10.4.1.141` in `/etc/ansible/hosts`

Comment: Try running Ansible with verbosity `-vvvvv` and then editing the result of that back into your question. I'd guess it's using the wrong username but it's hard to say without the extra debug info.

Comment: I added log in the description.

Comment: what are the privileges of ssh config? If they will be too open, you will have access denied (chmod should be 600 on ssh)

Comment: Yes, Its already there.

Comment: Could you explain us how you did provision your VM?

Comment: Provision your VM? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Have you tried adding your ssh key to your remote's `authorized_hosts` ?

Comment: Then the publickey should not fail, and no password should be asked. Can you detail the steps you have taken to ensure that your key is at the right place ?

Comment: your ssh command mentions `ssh user@10.4.1.141` but your ansible tries to login as user `rajatg`. Can you verify that this mismatch is not a copy-paster error in your question ?

Comment: no, i put put user only for more clarity. I used the same username.

Comment: I know this thread is coming up on 2 years old now, but I thought this information might be useful for future readers: If the IP you are using is **static** then I would recommend against posting it on public places. Just because you're showing access via a safe protocol (SSH) doesn't mean that you don't have other possible vulnerabilities (open ports for other applications maybe?) that could be exploited. Especially seeing as below you posted a username that may work for the server.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was in my `/etc/ansible/hosts` file.

The content written in `/etc/ansible/hosts` was `10.4.1.141`. But when I changed it to `rajat@10.4.1.141`, then the issue got fixed.

Comment: I think the proper solution in this case is `remote_user = rajat` into ansible.cfg.

Comment: It happen to me, and i was forced to wrote root as remote_user. Expected to be a default ...

Comment: A better way would be to have the host details in the local `inventory` file under each project and use `remote_user = rajat` into `ansible.cfg` as @bviktor suggested. This way you can use the same control node (having one project for each app/service) to run the playbook across all remote machines. This would help declutter host details in `/etc/ansible/hosts`

Answer (score 23):

If you log in with `ssh user@10.4.1.141`:

**Option 1**

Then make sure that in your hosts file inside `etc\ansible` you have:

```
[server01]
10.4.1.141
```

Then within `etc\ansible` run:

```
ansible all -m ping -u user --ask-pass
```

**Option 2**

If you want to log in without typing the SSH password then in your hosts file inside `etc\ansible` you add:

```
[server01]
10.4.1.141 ansible_ssh_pass=xxx ansible_ssh_user=user
```

Then within `etc\ansible` run:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

For me it worked both ways.

Comment: Its working, can you share without sharing pass in /etc/ansible/hosts file?

Comment: Note: for option 1, you may need to install `sshpass`.

Comment: Working on CentOS 7.9

Comment: I don't know if it's a great solution to store the SSH password in plaintext in the Ansible config file. It works, but to me it doesn't seem safe.

Answer (score 5):

My case is I have multiple private keys in my .ssh.

Here is how I fix it by telling ansible to use a certain private key

```sh
ansible-playbook -i ../../inventory.ini --private-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa_ansiadmin update.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous solutions didn't work for me, unfortunately ([DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) layman here!).

But the below one worked for me.

Change your inventory file to:

`[webserver] 10.4.1.141 ansible_user=ubuntu`

**ansible webserver --private-key pem_file.pem  -m ping**

Hitting the command with `-vvvv` helped me to debug it more.

Reference: *[Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password) #19584](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19584)*

Comment: I would upvote this a hundred times if I could.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute Ansible with sudo, for example

```
sudo ansible -m ping all
```

Please keep in mind that the **public key for root** has to be on the server you want to reach as well, not only the public key from your non-root-user. Otherwise, you get the error message above as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the issues happen while connecting Ubuntu machines in hosts.

Solution Ansible required which user want to connect, because Ubuntu doesn't have a default root user.

For the hosts file

[Test-Web-Server]

10.192.168.10  ansible_ssh_pass=foo ansible_ssh_user=foo

Comment: This is incomprehensible: *"Solution Ansible required which user want to connect"*

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the inventory file.

```
vi /etc/ansible/hosts
```

It should be:

```
[webserver]
192.###.###.### ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_ssh_pass=pass
```

Answer (score 2):

After years some OS require strong encryption of the SSH key, they don't support RSA and DSA keys. Therefore the message `Permission denied (publickey,password)` may indicate that OS needs strong SSH-key instead of id_rsa.

Use the following command to generate new key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa -N ""
```

Ensure that server has an option

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/openssh/sshd_config`.

Some other options may be required as well (**read the documentation of your OS first**), for example:

```
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin without-password
AuthorizedKeysFile  /etc/openssh/authorized_keys/%u /etc/openssh/authorized_keys2/%u .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Do not forget to restart sshd service to apply changes.

Copy the new key with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, then you can connect to remote server using ansible.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue as well.

My issue was also in my hosts file, `/etc/ansible/hosts`.

I changed my hosts file from

`172.28.2.101`

to

`name-of-server-in-ssh-config`

I had IP addresses in the hosts file. Since I have SSH configurations already set up for names, I do not need to use a variable or username in front of the hosts.

```
[name-stg-web]
server-name-stg-web[01:02]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the username in /etc/hosts file also can resolve the issue.

```
#sudo vim /etc/hosts
[test-server]
ip_address ansible_user="remote pc's username"
```

Answer (score 0):

What first worked for me was to hardcode the target machine root's password in the /etc/ansible/hosts like this:

```
[load_balancers_front]
loadbalancer1 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_user=root ansible_password=root_password_in_target
```

But it is **not recommended** to do this of course because of security issues.

Then, I figured out a solutions from the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html) by doing:

`ssh-agent bash` --> read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284374/ssh-keys-ssh-agent-bash-and-ssh-add)

and then

`ssh-add /my/private/ssh-key`

After this, my hosts file looks like this and `ansible all -m ping` works fine:

```
[load_balancers_front]
loadbalancer1 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_user=root
```

Answer (score 0):

[jenkinsserver]
publicdnsname    ansible_user=ubuntu  private_key=ubuntu.cer

Answer (score 0):

At the host machine you should install sshpass with the below command

```
              sudo apt install sshpass -y
```

and use this command to ping

```
     ansible all -i slaves.txt -m ping -u test --ask-pass
```

it will provide you keyboard interactive password entry, where you shall enter the passowrd of the slave machine